# How to add costume modules in Flowable 6.7.1 and Build it

Tags: flowable

I am using the Flowable engine 6.7.1 ([github](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine)), and I wanted to add my own some TaskListeners in the flowable. how to create new modules in Flowable 6.7.2, and how to build them, previous version 6.4.1 has the `all-in-one` folder with script and docker file to build the docker image, but the newer version doesn't have it.